# How does one access a file from subdirectory that contains specific termination?

Tags: c++

Supposing that I have the following structure:

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Folder\subfolder.suffix\wanted_file.txt`

- we know that in `Folder` there's only one `.suffix` subdirectory but we only know for sure its prefix ( the name may differ ).
- how can I get to `wanted_file.txt` ?

I've tried something like:

```
std::string halfpath = getenv("APPDATA");
std::string anotherhalfpath = "\\Folder\\*.suffix\\wanted_file.txt";
std::string finalpath = halfpath + anotherhalfpath;
```

It doesn't work this way (it prints 6-7 random chars).

The `finalpath` is being printed with `cout` if I remove `\\*.prefix\\wanted_file.txt` from the whole path, so I suppose the syntax that I've tried it's just not good.

I'd like, if possible, a solution that doesn't involve require `boost`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the terminology here seems a little off, a "prefix" is something that is put *before*, and a "suffix" is something that is put *after*.

Comment: It's just a typo, will make the changes

Comment: If you're limiting yourself to Windows which seems likely from the question, you can use FindFirstFile and friends which accepts wildcards. Or even just use FindFirstFile with "C:\Users\User\AppData\Folder\\*" to get the name of the directory.

Comment: I'm gonna try that out @MikeVine

Comment: @MikeVine , could you please improve your comment in an answer ? `FindFirstFile` might do its job but I can't get it work as it includes `windows.h` and I have to convert everything.

Comment: [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) contains a platform-independent filesystem library that can iterate files and directories. It might be an alternative to pulling in the WINAPI just for filesystem operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your environment supports the [Filesystem TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) (ISO/IEC TS 18822:2015) extension, the functionality of Boost.Filesystem is provided by `std::`.

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <algorithm>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // APPDATA, of course, is *NOT* portable
    std::path path_to_folder( getenv("APPDATA") );
    path_to_folder /= "Folder";
    std::directory_iterator it( path_to_folder );
    std::directory_iterator end;
    std::string suffix=".suffix";
    while ( it != end )
    {
        if ( suffix.length() <= filename.length()
             &&
             std::equals( suffix.rbegin(), suffix.rend(), filename.rbegin() )
        {
            std::cout << filename << "\n";
        }
        ++it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is supported, I am told, by [MSVC 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#stl) and Clang 3.5, with [GCC 5.3 catching up later in 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30103992/60281).

Later versions will probably include `<filesystem>` (without the "experimental"), making this the future-compatible solution.

Comment: @Alexander: Missed your "no Boost" requirement at first take. Fair enough. (Although I consider it a dubious and artificially crippling requirement.) -- However, Boost.Filesystem made it into the standard by now. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the folder and find the the one with the suffix, examples for iterating:

- [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c/14679177)
- [How do you get a directory listing in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-in-c/14679104)

My favorite approach is with the [tinydir](https://github.com/cxong/tinydir) single-header library, because it's simple and portable. Here's how you get the name of the folder that ends with the suffix (requires C++11 for std::move, you can just get rid of it):

```
std::string getDirWithSuffix(std::string path, std::string suffix) {
    tinydir_dir dir;
    std::string directory("");

    if(tinydir_open(&dir, path.c_str()) == -1) {
        return directory;
    }

    while(dir.has_next) {
        tinydir_file file;
        if(tinydir_readfile(&dir, &file) != -1) {
            if(file.is_dir) {
                std::string dirname(file.name);
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874134/find-if-string-endswith-another-string-in-c
                if(
                    dirname.length() >= suffix.length() &&
                    dirname.compare(dirname.length() - suffix.length(), suffix.length(), suffix) == 0
                ) {
                    directory = std::move(dirname);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        tinydir_next(&dir);
    }

    tinydir_close(&dir);
    return directory;
}
```