# experimental::filesystem linker error

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17

I try to use the new c++1z features actually on the head of development within gcc 6.0.

If I try this little example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
int main()
{
    fs::path p1 = "/home/pete/checkit";

    std::cout << "p1 = " << p1 << std::endl;
}
```

I got:

```
/opt/linux-gnu_6-20151011/bin/g++ --std=c++1z main.cpp -O2 -g -o go
/tmp/ccaGzqFO.o: In function \`std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::path(char const (&) [36])':
/opt/linux-gnu_6-20151011/include/c++/6.0.0/experimental/bits/fs_path.h:167: undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

gcc version is the snapshot linux-gnu_6-20151011

Any hints how to link for the new c++1z features?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

The Filesystem TS is nothing to do with C++1z support, it is a completely separate specification not part of the C++1z working draft.  GCC's implementation (in GCC 5.3 and later) is even available in C++11 mode.

You just need to link with `-lstdc++fs` to use it.

(The relevant library, `libstdc++fs.a`, is a static library, so as with any static library it should come *after* any objects that depend on it in the linker command.)

**Update Nov 2017:** as well as the Filesystem TS, GCC 8.x *also* has an implementation of the C++17 Filesystem library, defined in `<filesystem>` and in namespace `std::filesystem` (N.B. no "experimental" in those names) when using `-std=gnu++17` or `-std=c++17`. GCC's C++17 support is not complete or stable yet, and until it's considered ready for prime time use you also need to link to `-lstdc++fs` for the C++17 Filesystem features.

**Update Jan 2019:** starting with GCC 9, the C++17 `std::filesystem` components can be used without `-lstdc++fs` (but you still need that library for `std::experimental::filesystem`).

Comment: Is this documented anywhere, I tried to determine this myself and came up w/ nothing, did I miss some resource here?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, I've just updated the docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#table.ts_status https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using.html#manual.intro.using.flags https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.experimental (at the bottom)

Comment: When I try to use this I get the same linker error. `c++ -lstd++fs main.cpp`. I am using `gcc version 5.3.1 20151207 (Red Hat 5.3.1-2) (GCC) `

Comment: ok, `-lstdc++fs` has to be at the end of the line (after the source file at least). I don't understand why some `-lxxx` need to be at the end and others don't.

Comment: @alfC because that's how linkers work. References are resolved left to right, so you need to list static libraries after the objects that use them.

Comment: No problem, the idea was to improve the answer. These comments will be deleted soon.

Comment: As reported here, std::filesystem is part of C++17.

Comment: @Pietro but this question is about `std::experimental::filesystem` (the TS) which is not the same thing. I repeat, _The Filesystem TS is nothing to do with C++1z support, it is a completely separate specification not part of the C++1z working draft._

Comment: Are you saying that, in trunk, `-stdc++fs` implements both Filesystem TS, and C++17 filesystem?

Comment: How about GCC 8.2.1?  I just tried, and it seems like GCC 8 still requires `-lstdc++fs` but it is kind of odd because GCC 8 support full set of C++17.  No?

Comment: @HCSF, No, GCC 8 does not support full C++17, and what part of "starting with GCC 9, the C++17 `std::filesystem` components can be used without `-lstdc++fs`" is not clear?

Comment: My distro doesn't have GCC 9 yet.  And I thought GCC 8 supports full C++17, and so I felt strange that `-lstdc++fs` was still required for a compiler that supports full C++17.  That's why I asked.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: how do I add the -lstdc++fs to my CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Note that with `g++` version 7.5.x and with `-std=c++17`, it's marked as experimental. So you need the `-lstdc++fs` trick and the `experimental` namespace. (that's the default compile on Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: @AlexisWilke I've clarified the answer to say that the C++17 `std::filesystem` code is only available from GCC 8, so yes, you need to use `std::experimental::filesystem` with GCC 7 (whether or not you compile with `-std=c++17`).

Answer (score 59):

If you are using cmake, add the following line to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
link_libraries(stdc++fs)
```

So that cmake can link against the corresponding library.

Comment: I did `target_link_libraries(hello_world_ stdc++fs)` and it compiled.

Comment: `target_link_libraries` did not work for me in `g++-8`. This worked

Answer (score 14):

With clang 4.0+, you need to link against `libc++experimental.a`

Make sure you're building with libc++ (not libstdc++) with the -stdlib=libc++ (as mentioned in the comments)

Comment: I also needed -stdlib=libc++ because my clang version was unexpectedly using libstdc++.

Comment: @BowieOwens thanks, updated answer to make that clear.

Comment: When you say "make sure you're building with libc++", how do I do this?  (Solution preferably with CMake.) . Thanks.

Comment: @mannyglover `-stdlib=libc++`  or `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")`

Answer (score 7):

Here is a demo that might be helpful to someone in the future:

env: `el6`, `gcc/5.5.0`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <experimental/filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::string path = std::experimental::filesystem::current_path();

    std::cout << "path = " << path << std::endl;
}
```

The following are compiling and testing. The flags are `-std=c++17` `-lstdc++fs`:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/apps/gcc-5.5.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.5.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/apps/gcc-5.5.0 --disable-multilib --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-languages=all
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.5.0 (GCC)

$ ls -lrt /apps/gcc-5.5.0/lib64 | grep libstdc
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  11272436 Jun 25 10:51 libstdc++.so.6.0.21
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      2419 Jun 25 10:51 libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       976 Jun 25 10:51 libstdc++.la
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  11272436 Jun 25 10:51 libstdc++.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  10581732 Jun 25 10:51 libstdc++fs.a
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  28985412 Jun 25 10:51 libstdc++.a
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       916 Jun 25 10:51 libstdc++fs.la
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  11272436 Jun 25 10:51 libstdc++.so.6

$ g++ filesystem-testing.cpp -lstdc++fs -std=c++17
$ ./a.out

$ g++ -std=c++17 filesystem-testing.cpp -lstdc++fs
$ ./a.out
path = /home/userid/projects-c++/filesystem-testing
```

It also works with flags: `-std=c++11`

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 filesystem-testing.cpp -lstdc++fs
$ ./a.out
path = /home/userid/projects-c++/filesystem-testing
```

The follows had compiling error `_ZNSt12experimental10filesystem2v112current_pathB5cxx11Ev`

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs filesystem-testing.cpp
/tmp/ccA6Q9oF.o: In function `main':
filesystem-testing.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `_ZNSt12experimental10filesystem2v112current_pathB5cxx11Ev'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

## Extra Notes:

The following link might be helpful

[How to install gcc8 using devtoolset-8-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310625/how-to-install-gcc8-using-devtoolset-8-gcc)

Answer (score 1):

For

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: 
__ZNSt3__14__fs10filesystem4path17replace_extensionERKS2_
```

and

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   
"std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__current_path(std::__1::error_code*)", 
referenced from:      
sys::path::get_cwd() in Path.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

.. try the following:

For LLVM clang >= 10, link with `libc++.1.0.dylib` supplied by LLVM.

```
add_link_options("-Wl,-rpath,location_of_llvm_install/lib;location_of_llvm_install/lib/libc++.1.0.dylib")
```

This is not for Apple Clang, but for LLVM clang installed from official https://releases.llvm.org or by a package manager.

Xcode  < 11 doesn't have filesystem header. macOS < 10.15 doesn't have `std::filesystem::path` symbols in the system dylib at `/usr/lib/libc++.1.0.dylib`

Answer (score 0):

[You can easily try my code online.](https://repl.it/@henkish/showPath#main.cpp)

```
//  currentPath.cpp
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149878#65128193
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "path = " << experimental::filesystem::current_path() << endl;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
clang++ currentPath.cpp -lstdc++fs && ./a.out # Linux
clang++ currentPath.cpp -lstdc++fs && ./a.exe # MSYS2, Windows
```

Note: `-lstdc++fs` is a linker flag, not a compiler flag.
(Important when you write a makefile.)

Expected output:

```
path = "/path/to/the/current/directory"
```

Comment: If you try to compile and run my code, I believe you will see a good reason to upvote my answer. If you _do_ compile and run, and still don't want to upvote, please consider letting my know **why** in a comment below. - Admittedly, my answer does have similarities with the answer by @caot, but there are also some significant differences. This is why I prefer to publish an answer of my own rather than suggesting edits to _caot_'s answer.