# Why path escape character is different for boost::filesystem::path and std::filesystem::path?

Tags: c++, path, standards, c++17, boost-filesystem

`boost::filesystem::path` uses `&` to escape quotes in path string, [see demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VtcyuL3K0VGj32l1):

```
std::cout << boost::filesystem::path("/R&D/Project \"boost\"") << std::endl;
```

Prints `"/R&&D/Project &"boost&""`. However, for `std::filesystem::path` [I see this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt):

> Performs stream input or output on the path p. std::quoted is used so that spaces are not truncation when later read by stream input operator.

Here is from [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted):

> escape - the character to use as the escape character, defaults to \

From this I can tell that `std::filesystem::path` will use `\` instead of `&`.

Is this correct? If yes, why the committee decided to change this behavior?

Bonus question: are there any implementations of `std::filesystem::path` available? Seems like none of latest GCC and clang provide `<filesystem>` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If yes, why the committee decided to change this behavior?

From [N3399](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3399.html), emphasized is mine:

> The Boost inserter outputs quoted strings, which are recognized as such by the extractor. **There is a sentiment within the Filesystem Study Group that supplying a quoted and/or escaped string manipulator as a string extension would be a better solution than a path specific feature.** See proposal [N3431](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3431.html), Quoted Strings Library Proposal.

That said, the filesystem study group think it's better to use `quoted` string manipulator than a specific feature for `path`

> Bonus question: are there any implementations of std::filesystem::path available? Seems like none of latest GCC and clang provide  header.

AFAIK, major compilers like g++, clang, msvc both provides `filesystem` as an experimental feature with `<experimental/filesystem>` in namespace `std::experimental::filesystem`. gcc has it from version 5.3 as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159746/4115625), MSVC has it from VS2012 (it's `<filesystem>` in VS2012 and VS2013, then move to `<experimental/filesystem>` and `<filesystem>` in VS2015)

Comment: Great, thanks for the quote! As for experimental, I tried it in online compilers with no success: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nfZ88PnrttOGbEHu Maybe its just a problem in online compiler.

Comment: @Mikhail As Jonathan had mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33159746/4115625), you must link it with `-lstdc++fs` See [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/75pJtT4K3dAgGT1i)

Answer (score 2):

Boost::Filesystem is fairly old, and predates C++14's `quoted`. It's entirely reasonable for the standard to be internally consistent. Following Boost is only a secondary concern.