# Cannot use the C++ `std::filesystem` library with Meson build

Tags: c++, clang, boost-filesystem, meson-build

I am trying to build a piece of C++ code that uses the new C++17 Filesystem library, using the Meson build system.

This is the piece of `meson.build` file involved:

```
if not compiler.has_header('filesystem')   # This is OK
    warning('The compiler has no <filesystem> header file')
endif

filesystem_dep = dependency('libc++fs', modules : ['filesystem'])

test_exe = executable('test', test_src,
                      include_directories : include_dirs,
                      dependencies : filesystem_dep
                     )
```

In case the boost::filesystem library is used, this should be the correct syntax:

```
filesystem_dep = dependency('boost', modules : ['filesystem'])
```

How can I specify I want the version contained in the Standard C++ library? This is what I tried without success: 'libc++fs', 'stdlib', 'stdc++', 'libc++', 'c++', 'c++17'.

This is the error message I get from Meson:

> src/meson.build:33:0: ERROR:  Native dependency 'libc++fs' not found

The compiler I am currently using is LLVM/clang.

Comment: (not using clang nor meson, so I may be wrong, but) have you checked if you need to link libc++fs with clang if you use std::filesystem?

Comment: @roalz - I think Meson should deal with it, and choose `libc++fs` or `libstdc++fs` depending on the compiler (clang or gcc).

Answer (score 3):

**dependency()** is for external libraries. Standard libraries should be configured using compiler command line with special functions like [add_XXX_arguments()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#add_project_arguments). So, try

```
add_project_arguments(['-stdlib=libc++'], language : 'cpp')
add_project_link_arguments(['-stdlib=libc++','-lstdc++fs'], language : 'cpp')
```

However, '-lstdc++fs' maybe not needed in your [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129775/why-must-i-still-use-lstdcfs).