# NetBeans IDE, C++, and link -lstdc++fs

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am having the same problem as the asker in Stack Overflow question *[experimental::filesystem linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149878/experimentalfilesystem-linker-error)*. The accepted answer is to link, `-lstdc++fs`.

How do I link -lstdc++fs in the IDE I am using (NetBeans)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add stdc++fs to your project's libraries.

1. Right click on your project
2. Select **Properties**
3. In the Project Properties dialog, select **Build->Linker**
4. To the right of Libraries, click the **"..."** button
5. Click **Add Library**
6. Type "stdc++fs" in the File Name box. There is no need to browse for the file.
7. Click **Select**
8. Click **OK**
9. Click **OK**