# Cant link filesystem library con C++

Tags: c++, filesystems

I'm having troubles to link the filesystem library on C++. I have gcc 8.2.0:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    std::string path = "/";
    for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path))
        std::cout << p << std::endl;

}
```

Here is my makefile:

```
CC= g++-8.2.0
CFLAGS= -Iheaders -std=c++17  -Wall

all: lsr 

lsr: lsr.o
  ${CC} ${CFLAGS} $? -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
  ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c $<

clean:
  rm -f *.o lsr
```

gcc (Gentoo 8.2.0-r3 p1.4) 8.2.0

How can I fix it? :S

Answer (score 1):

Actually the filesystem library is not part of the standard library in gcc at this stage (same for clang and MSVC). The reason is the unstable ABI at this stage.
You must add  `-lstdc++fs` to your link stage as described in [experimental::filesystem linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149878/experimentalfilesystem-linker-error) (IIRC).

Comment: I get the same error. CFLAGS= -Iheaders -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs -Wall

Comment: Can you tell us the actual error, at least partially? Perhaps you don't have this library installed?

Comment: This is the error: https://pastebin.com/EQvbmXdf

It is in spanish, but there are not much words in. If it is not installed, how can I know that? And how to install it?

Comment: That's very odd, because these missing symbols are the ones coming from this additional library. Can you give us the state of your makefile after the link addition?

Comment: Sure: https://pastebin.com/AaLe3qYx
I also tried like this: https://pastebin.com/zk0eJ2Jb

Comment: I have 2 versions of gcc installed. 8.2 and 7.3. I'm using 8.2. Shall i Unistall the previous version?

Comment: Fixed! The -lstd++fs has to be put AFTER the file.o to be compiled, not before.

Comment: Oh, it's the traditional I link progressively from left to right and if I don't need something, it gets dropped.