# How to install gcc8 using devtoolset-8-gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, centos7

I am using CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 which has gcc 4.8.5 20150623 installed.  I am looking for a way to install a newer version of gcc, specially 8.1.  I found the following site on how to install gcc v7 [link 1](https://ahelpme.com/linux/centos7/how-to-install-new-gcc-and-development-tools-under-centos-7/) which describes how to install gcc v7 (using devtoolset-7-gcc*).  I did follow the guidelines and was able to install gcc v7.  Though, if I followed the same procedure, but used "devtoolset-8-gcc*" instead the return message states "No package devtoolset-8-gcc* available.".

Performed a search and found a page called "Information for build devtoolset-8-gcc-8.1.1-4.el6" [link 2](https://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=23600), but not sure how to install this.  I believe I would need to download the rpm source, compile/build the source, then finally install it.

Basically, I am looking for a easy way to install gcc v8 just like using the method described on link 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[devtoolset-8](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2018:3561) was only released a short while ago.  The linked [installation instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/8/html/user_guide/chap-red_hat_developer_toolset#sect-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset-Subscribe-RHSCL) may be of use.  However, your question pertains to CentOS, and this does not yet appear to have been made available yet.  You can see some evidence of it being build for CentOS [here](https://cbs.centos.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=7198), but it's not been updated for the final release yet.

You could ask on the SCL mailing list for an ETA, or wait until it appears in its final form.  In the meantime, you could download the RPMs from koji directly.

Comment: As of March 2019, `devtoolset-8` seems to be installable. See also: https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/updates/

Answer (score 18):

To install the full tools-set including gfortran on centos 7:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install devtoolset-8
scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash
```

enable the tools:

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable
```

you may wish to put the command above in .bash_profile

ref: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477360/centos-7-gcc-8-installation

Answer (score 5):

The follows worked in `centos/rhel 7`.

- How to install it?

```
# rpm -ivh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-scl-rh-2-3.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
# yum install devtoolset-8
```

Here is the `rpm` from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/ that might be needed to be updated accordingly.

- How to use it?

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The flags `-std=c++17 -lstdc++fs` and the following line could be helpful.

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
```