# After update of llvm cannot find <filesystem> references on macOS with hombrew

Tags: c++, macos

I have updated my llvm installation, such that I now use Clang8. 
After that I keep getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__status(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__fs::filesystem::is_directory(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&) in main-de2419.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So it can find the header for `filesystem` but not the lib (as I understand). I have this test program:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    auto isDir = std::filesystem::is_directory("./main.cpp");
    std::cout << isDir << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

And I compile it this way `clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp`. If with `-v` the output is:

```
clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
 "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/bin/clang-8" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -ggnu-pubnames -target-linker-version 409.12 -v -resource-dir /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/lib/clang/8.0.0 -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1 -std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/larsnielsen/Desktop/test/test_filesystem -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 160 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/df/wm8q24k53dz09jn4q35122bw0000gn/T/main-2be1ed.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 based upon LLVM 8.0.0 default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.14.0 -o a.out /var/folders/df/wm8q24k53dz09jn4q35122bw0000gn/T/main-2be1ed.o -lc++ -lSystem /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__status(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__fs::filesystem::is_directory(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&) in main-2be1ed.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have trieded a few solution options, without success:

- I have changed to use `<experimental/filesystem>`
- I have tried to link `stdc++fs` and `c++fs`
- I have tried to export `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"` and `CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"`
- And I have added this to my .bash_profile `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"`

I have update LLVM on both my Fedora and macOS, and only the Mac has the issue. I updated using homebrew on macOS.

Comment: What's the error with stdc++fs? Because that's what's missing (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807011/undefined-reference-error-with-new-filesystem-library-and-clang7)

Comment: It says `ld: library not found for -lstdc++fs` but the post you link to may have an answer.

Comment: nope tried to swap for `-lc++fs` didn't work either

Comment: OK, so that means that you don't have the library installed. Can you check that libc++fs is on your system?

Comment: I have this `libc++fs.a` in `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/lib/`

Comment: AHA! thanks @MatthieuBrucher It is because the link paths are not updated

Comment: eh how can I add setup that permantly ?

Comment: It should have been done by the driver (clang++), it should point to the right folders directly. Are you sure the right one is used for the link?

Comment: it uses the one xcode uses

Comment: And that one probably doesn't know about clang 8.0. It should use the 8.0 driver, not the XCode one.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149878/experimentalfilesystem-linker-error/64982538#64982538

Comment: I fixed it using isysroot, I just forgot to update this question