# Passing std::filesystem::path to a function segfaults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17, std-filesystem

When I attempt to use `std::filesystem::path` as a function argument, it segfaults on my machine. Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <filesystem>

void thing(const std::filesystem::path& p) {
    return;
}

int main() {
    thing("test");
    return 0;
}
```

This snippet results in the following backtrace from gdb:

```
#0  0x0000563a5a3814b3 in std::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::~vector (this=0x23, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:567
#1  0x0000563a5a38132c in std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::~path (this=0x3, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:208
#2  0x0000563a5a381f74 in std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt::~_Cmpt (this=0x3, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:643
#3  0x0000563a5a381f8f in std::_Destroy<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> (__pointer=0x3) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:98
#4  0x0000563a5a381e3f in std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt*> (__first=0x3, __last=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:108
#5  0x0000563a5a381ab0 in std::_Destroy<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt*> (__first=0x3, __last=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:137
#6  0x0000563a5a3817c1 in std::_Destroy<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt*, std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> (__first=0x3, __last=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:206
#7  0x0000563a5a3814c9 in std::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::~vector (this=0x7ffd198df8a0 = {...}, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:567
#8  0x0000563a5a38132c in std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::~path (this=0x7ffd198df880<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x2b>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:208
#9  0x0000563a5a381247 in main () at /home/user/CLionProjects/test/main.cpp:8
#10 0x00007fd6bb96ab6b in __libc_start_main (main=0x563a5a381200 <main()>, argc=1, argv=0x7ffd198df9b8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffd198df9a8) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#11 0x0000563a5a38113a in _start ()
```

I am using GCC 8.3 on Ubuntu 19.10, I had someone else compile and run this code with no issues on Windows so it could potentially be a bug in `libstdc++`

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 won't be out until October, presumably you mean 18.10?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the problem is that Ubuntu mixes GCC versions in a single installation. On Ubuntu the default GCC is version 8, but the `libstdc++.so.6` library comes from GCC 9. With GCC 8 the `std::filesystem` definitions are in a separate library, `libstdc++fs.a`, which must be linked to explicitly. In GCC 9 the `std::filesystem` symbols are in the main `libstdc++.so` library. Because of the mixed up Ubuntu installation it's possible for the GCC 9 symbols in `libstdc++.so` to satisfy the undefined references in code compiled with GCC 8 which **should** be satisfied by `libstdc++fs.a`. Because the `std::filesystem` symbols in GCC 9 are incompatible with the experimental versions of those symbols in GCC 8, it appears to link OK but crashes at runtime.

It should work correctly if you make sure you link with `-lstdc++fs` and make sure that option comes after all your object files, e.g. this should work:

```
g++ foo.o bar.o -lstdc++fs
```

But this will **not** work:

```
g++ -lstdc++fs foo.o bar.o
```

There is supposed to be an update to the Ubuntu `gcc-8` packages to fix this, by ensuring the `-lstdc++fs` option comes after all the other input files. For more details see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-8/+bug/1824721

Compiling with `gcc-9` also works, because when using GCC 9 to compile there is no need to link to `-lstdc++fs` for `std::filesystem`  (with GCC 9 it's only needed for `std::experimental::filesystem` symbols).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by installing GCC and G++ 9 from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test

Comment: Using G++9 worked for me too `sudo apt install g++-9` on 19.04 without this PPA. Also removed g++8 and updated the g++ alternatives list `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 10`

Answer (score 1):

Please link `-lstdc++fs` library, let's consider source file is fileSys.cpp then compile it as follows,
`g++ -std=c++17 fileSys.cpp -lstdc++fs -o fs`

I am using `GCC 8.1.0` and `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`.
There is already a similar question on this topic, you can find it at [filesystem linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149878/experimentalfilesystem-linker-error)

Comment: @AlanBirtles: So you can compile it successfully without linking ```stdc++fs``` library?

Comment: I haven't tried but the OP has posted a runtime error so he must be able to link correctly

Comment: Please try to compile it without linking ```stdc++fs``` library.

Comment: I'm sure it won't work but it's still not related to this question