# Segmentation fault when exiting from a class in which an std::filesystem::path object is specified

Tags: c++, std-filesystem

I face a problem in my program that I can't get over it. I have a class in which I have declared an attribute like `std::filesystem::path p {"path/to/save/dir"};`. And I have in the same class a method which saves some data to a .txt file. First I check some things like if the user has given an extension and then if a file with the same name exists. So if the user does not want to overwrite it, I ask him for a new name file. Then I write to the file. So, **the problem** is that whenever the program exits the class a seg fault will pop and specifically for the save method if it goes into the if clause then it will not save as it will recieve seg fault. I think that it has to do with the destructor of the class and calling the destructor of the path object.

Using gdb, I got this as the message:

```
0x0000555555558907 in std::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::~vector (this=0x20, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:567
567     std::_Destroy(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
```

**Things I have tried so far:**

- I have tried explicitly calling the `std::filesystem::path`
  destructor (my class does not have a destructor method specified
  right now). Did not work.
- I have tried moving the path object outside the class, "converting"
  it to a global object. The problem would now occur only when I would
  exit from the main.cpp file where I declare the class object*****. But not
  when I would exit from the class.
- I have tried to clear the path with the clear method but it would not
  be called for some reason that I never understood. So it did not do
  anything.

*:

```
case 1: {
        Game g1(true);

        while(g1.play()){}

        break;
      }
```

Essentially, this is a part of the main.cpp. It has a menu followed by a switch statement analogous with the selection of the user. So when it exists from the loop  and breaks and I choose to exit I recieve the seg fault.

Any help is appriciated, thanks.

Comment: I recall a GCC bug. [Is this similar to your problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615841/passing-stdfilesystempath-to-a-function-segfaults)

Comment: @user4581301 It looks to be simillar error-wise at least.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed**

So after @user4581301 told me that was a GCC bug I researced it differently and found out that it was indeed a GCC 8.3.0 bug. It is fixed in GCC 9 or GCC 8.3.0-7ubuntu (though experimental). So the "hotfix" for now is to add `-lstdc++fs` after the source files and no error will be shown. Program works as expected!