# c++ std::bad_alloc on std::filesystem::path append

Tags: c++, exception, gdb, c++17, libstdc++

I am experiencing a very strange behavior, which I distilled down to a very basic test:

```
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

int main(void)
{
  const std::string name = "foo";
  const std::filesystem::path lock_dir = "/tmp";
  std::filesystem::path lockfile = lock_dir / name;

  return 0;
}
```

I compile this with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g foo.cpp -o foo`. When I run it, I get a std::bad_alloc exception on the line where the two paths are appended. Here's what I see with gdb

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff742c801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7a8e1f2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7a99e36 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7a99e81 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7a9a0b5 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7a907a7 in std::__throw_bad_alloc() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000555555558cfe in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt>::allocate (this=0x7fffffffe080, __n=12297828079348111650) at /usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:102
#8  0x00005555555587d0 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::allocate (__a=..., __n=12297828079348111650) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/alloc_traits.h:436
#9  0x0000555555557f76 in std::_Vector_base<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::_M_allocate (this=0x7fffffffe080, __n=12297828079348111650)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:296
#10 0x0000555555558387 in std::_Vector_base<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::_M_create_storage (this=0x7fffffffe080, __n=12297828079348111650)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:311
#11 0x00005555555579cf in std::_Vector_base<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffe080, __n=12297828079348111650, __a=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:260
#12 0x0000555555556d39 in std::vector<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt, std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::_Cmpt> >::vector (this=0x7fffffffe080, 
    __x=std::vector of length -1303124922760, capacity -1303124922760 = {...}) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:460
#13 0x000055555555635f in std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::path (this=0x7fffffffe060, Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member or method named _M_t.: 
__p=...) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:166
#14 0x00005555555563c8 in std::filesystem:: (Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member or method named _M_t.: 
__lhs=..., Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member or method named _M_t.: 
__rhs=...) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h:554
#15 0x0000555555555fbe in main () at foo.cpp:8
```

This brings up several questions:

1. What is wrong with my test code?
2. Why does GDB show anything with python in the call stack?

Anticipating the question, my g++ is `gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1)` and my gdb is `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.2-0ubuntu1~18.04) 8.2`

**UPDATE** Here is the output of ldd for the successfully compiled executable

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc697b2000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5c35444000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5c3522c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5c34e3b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5c34a9d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5c35a2d000)
```

Comment: Do you notice any difference if you add `-lstdc++fs` when compiling/linking?

Comment: @TedLyngmo without it he would have a linking issue.

Comment: [Here it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yrGK19ZasFCUyZeP) with no problems it must be some problem on your machine.

Comment: @MarekR I wasn't sure what issue OP has really and since I think gcc 8 wants `-lstdc++fs` (while gcc 9 seems to be fine without it) I thought it would be worth a try..

Comment: the python stuff is just some GDB plugin which failed during debugging (when it tried make some stuff human readable). Does your error appears during regular run or just when you debug your code?

Comment: @MarekR - I suspect that my Ubuntu VM may be at fault here. I just did a `apt update && apt upgrade` and perhaps this is somehow related

Comment: This error appears during regular run

Comment: I wonder how you can compile using gcc 8.3.0 without `-lstdc++fs`. It should fail ... :-/

Comment: @TedLyngmo - I added ldd info for the executable. It clearly links and runs, except for the bad_alloc exception which I am trying to track down with this question

Comment: @PaulGrinberg Ok, and if you add `-lstdc++fs` when compiling and then do `ldd`, any difference?

Comment: @TedLyngmo - no difference on either `ldd` output or crash behavior when I add `-lstdc++fs

Comment: Ok, and what version is `libstdc++.so.6` pointing at? `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` should show the full version, like `libstdc++.so.6.0.25` for gcc 8 and `libstdc++.so.6.0.26` for gcc 9..

Comment: @TedLyngmo - I think you may be onto something: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.26`

Comment: :-) Yeah, it's definitely linked with the gcc 9 lib. That would explain why linking without `-lstdc++fs` worked. No idea how that could happen. Perhaps your development tools didn't get the same update as the libraries when you updated...? odd ...

Comment: Here is another data point. In my bad VM, I can compile/link a bad executable with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g foo.cpp -o foo`. When I compile/link with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g foo.cpp -o foo -lstdc++fs` it runs without a problem

Comment: Odd indeed ... I wish I had an answer, but now you know where do start looking at least. :)

Comment: According to stacktrace, things go wrong when there was an attempt to allocate vector of size `12297828079348111650`.

Comment: Could it be some interaction between GCC 8.3 and the GCC 9 lib?

Comment: The Python business is a bug in GDB’s libraries (which are in Python) for pretty-printing C++ objects mentioned in the traceback.

Comment: I thought I was on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, so it was a surprise to me to find out that somehow I had `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-bionic.list` which is which is how my system got broken.

Comment: @TedLyngmo your comments above are spot on and would be 100% correct, if it wasn't for a "feature" of Ubuntu. It's by design that Ubuntu ships inconsistent headers and shared library for libstdc++, and that's why the program links without using `-lstdc++fs`, and that's why it crashes at runtime. See my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is caused by a "feature" of Ubuntu, which provides a later `libstdc++.so` than the one that comes with the system `g++`. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-8/+bug/1824721 for more details.

Normally when compiling with GCC 8 the `std::filesystem` symbols are not present in `libstdc++.so` and so if you fail to [link with `-lstdc++fs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159746/981959) then you will get a linker error. But because the newer `libstdc++.so` from GCC 9 *does* include symbols for `std::filesystem`, that linker error doesn't happen. Unfortunately, the GCC 9 versions of the filesystem symbols are not compatible with the GCC 8 headers (because the filesystem library was experimental and unstable in GCC 8, and the layout of `filesystem::path` changed for GCC 9). This means that your program links, but then at runtime it uses the wrong symbols for `filesystem::path`, and bad things happen.

I didn't anticipate this problem, because I didn't know Ubuntu mixes old libstdc++ headers with a new libstdc++ shared library. That's usually safe to do, **except** [when using "experimental", incomplete features, such as the C++17 features in GCC 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119902/981959).

The fix I suggested for Ubuntu was to make `g++` automatically add `-lstdc++fs` to the end of your compilation command. If you use any `std::filesystem` features then the correct definitions for those symbols should be found in GCC 8's `libstdc++fs.a` (rather than in GCC 9's `libstdc++.so`) and in most cases everything should Just Work. If Ubuntu didn't update their GCC packages with that workaround yet, you can also make it work by just making sure you manually link with `-lstdc++fs` (which is documented as required for GCC 8 anyway).

Comment: Whoa... nasty :-) Good to know! I'm running Ubuntu at work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yeah, what should have been a linker error if you forget `-lstdc++fs` becomes undefined behaviour and a runtime crash. Nasty. According to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90050#c8 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-8/+bug/1824721/comments/17 it should now be fixed, so be sure you're up to date.

Comment: My local machine is probably updated then but I should probably check what they run in the containers in the CI machinery where `boost::filesystem` is part of the mix too.

Answer (score 4):

I'll summarize my own findings with what other folks found in the comments. That's not an actual answer (yet), since at this time I cannot explain the reason of the failure.

I was able to reproduce this behavior by installing g++-8 and g++-9 inside a regular `ubuntu` Docker image, so that I had both `/usr/bin/g++-8` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.26` available.

According to the `gdb` stack trace, the error happens somewhere in `std::vector` constructor. Seems like it happens when the default copy constructor for `std::filesystem::path` is called inside its `operator/`:

`/usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h`

```cpp
  /// Append one path to another
  inline path operator/(const path& __lhs, const path& __rhs)
  {
    path __result(__lhs);  // <-- fails here
    __result /= __rhs;
    return __result;
  }
```

This finding makes it possible to simplify the test case even more:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>

int main(void)
{
  const std::filesystem::path first = "/tmp";
  const std::filesystem::path second(first);

  return 0;
}
```

which makes it clear that the problem is somewhere in calling the copy constructor.

The only `vector` in `std::filesystem::path` is this vector (presumably, of path components):

`/usr/include/c++/8/bits/fs_path.h`

```cpp
    struct _Cmpt;
    using _List = _GLIBCXX_STD_C::vector<_Cmpt>;
    _List _M_cmpts; // empty unless _M_type == _Type::_Multi
```

According to the stack trace, when copying this vector, we immediately get into `stl_vector.h`:

`/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h`

```cpp
      vector(const vector& __x)
      : _Base(__x.size(),
        _Alloc_traits::_S_select_on_copy(__x._M_get_Tp_allocator()))
      {
```

but if we print the value of `__n` in the constructor of `_Vector_base` here:

```cpp
      _Vector_base(size_t __n, const allocator_type& __a)
      : _M_impl(__a)
      { _M_create_storage(__n); }
```

we'll get some insanely large number, which makes me think that an incorrect vector `__x` was somehow passed down to the copy constructor.

Now, why that happens when you combine g++-8 with the libraries of g++-9, I have no idea (for now) and I'm guessing one should go one level deeper if they need to understand the real reason.

But the answer to your main question, I guess, is "The problem is caused by an incompatibility between your compiler and library versions" :)

Comment: It looks like the constructor calls _M_spit_cmpts which somehow leaves the vector borked.

Comment: _"The problem is caused by an incompatibility between your compiler and library versions"_ -- you're right, the problem is that the OP didn't create that incompatibility, Ubuntu did :-( See my answer for the missing pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWakely - your answer should be the accepted one :)