# C++ dynamic stdc++ symbol used even though shared object has static version of symbol included

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, c++17

I have a (linux) shared object compiled against GCC 8.4, which statically links in stdc++fs.  This shared object is then used and run on other systems with newer stdc++ runtimes and it only sometimes works, other times it crashes on the deconstruction of `filesystem::path`.

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63902528/program-crashes-when-filesystempath-is-destroyed) as a guide to understanding the symbol and what is partially going on, however I do not understand why it fails only sometimes.

I can recreate the issue by changing how a working program loads a different c++ shared object before mine is loaded.

## Working

This is captured from a Java program that uses a JNI to load my shared object

```
binding file /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSt10filesystem4path14_M_split_cmptsEv' [GLIBCXX_3.4.26]
//later on
binding file libmyso.so [0] to libmyso.so [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSt10filesystem4path14_M_split_cmptsEv'
```

## Non-Working

This is captured from the same Java program, but with a LD_PRELOAD on LLVM forced, to try an emulate this symbol being loaded before reaching my library (as believed to be the case in the non-functioning cases)

```
binding file /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSt10filesystem4path14_M_split_cmptsEv' [GLIBCXX_3.4.26]
//later on
binding file libmyso.so [0] to /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSt10filesystem4path14_M_split_cmptsEv'
```

Based on the linked post above, I have to believe the cause of the crash is due to incompatible versions of the symbol listed here.  What I am trying to understand is why my symbol is not using the locally supplied one (via statically linking stdc++fs) in the second case?

Comment: `filesystem::~path` what is that? This is not a valid symbol in C++.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I used filesystem::~path as a short hand for the deconstruction of the path object.  I have changed it to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand that the difference between Working and Not Working lies
in a difference in the load order of the shared libraries on which
your program depends. What causes that difference in load order is
out scope for this answer as you evidently consider it out of scope
for the question.

> What I am trying to understand is why my symbol is not using the locally
> supplied one (via statically linking stdc++fs) in the second case

It appears you are under the impression that if the definition of
a dynamically visible symbol `sym` is statically linked into a shared library `liblate.so`
then references to `sym` within `liblate.so` itself will by default be bound
to it's own definition of `sym` at runtime, even
if the dynamic linker has already loaded another shared library `libfirst.so` that is
the first provider of a dynamically visible definition of `sym`.

This is not so. By default, *all* references to `sym` in the program will
be bound to the first definition that the dynamic linker finds - the one provided by `libfirst.so`

Here is an elementary demonstration of that. See the comments.

```
$ cat barcat.cpp
#include <string>

std::string bar()
{
    // bar() returns a string identifying the source file
    // from which it was compiled.
    return "bar from " __FILE_NAME__;
}

std::string cat(std::string const & lhs, std::string const & rhs)
{
    // cat() returns the concatenation of its argument strings.
    return lhs + rhs;
}


$ cat foobar.cpp
#include <string>

extern std::string cat(std::string const &, std::string const &);  

std::string bar()
{
    // bar() returns a string identifying the source file
    // from which it was compiled.
    return "bar from " __FILE_NAME__;
}

std::string foobar()
{
    // foobar() returns a string saying that it is calling bar(),
    // and does so.
    return cat("foobar calling ",bar());
}

$ cat main.cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

extern std::string cat(std::string const &, std::string const &);
extern std::string foobar();

int main()
{
    std::cout << cat("main() calling ",foobar()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Yes, `barcat.cpp` and `foobar.cpp` are both supposed to contain definitions of `bar`. Now we'll compile the sources:

```
$ g++ -c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -fPIC barcat.cpp foobar.cpp
$ g++ -c -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic main.cpp
```

Then make two shared libraries:

```
$ g++ -shared -o libbarcat.so barcat.o
$ g++ -shared -o libfoobar.so foobar.o
```

`libbarcat.so` statically links dynamically visible definitions of
`bar` and `cat`. `libfoobar.so` statically links dynamically visible
definitions of `bar` - again! - and `foobar`. As we can see:

```
$ readelf -W --dyn-syms libbarcat.so | c++filt | egrep .*(Symbol|Ndx| bar| cat) 
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 45 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    29: 00000000000024f9   165 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 bar[abi:cxx11]()
    31: 000000000000259e    88 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 cat(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
    
$ readelf -W --dyn-syms libfoobar.so | c++filt | egrep .*(Symbol|Ndx| bar| foobar) 
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 38 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    24: 0000000000002439   165 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 bar[abi:cxx11]()
    35: 00000000000024de   257 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 foobar[abi:cxx11]()
```

The static linkage e.g.:

```
$ g++ -shared -o libfoobar.so foobar.o
```

is exactly the same as if `foobar.o` was a static library member `libname.a(foobar.o)` in the
linkage:

```
$ g++ -shared -o libfoobar.so -L /some/path -l name
```

where `-l name` gets resolved to `/some/path/libname.a`.

Now we'll link a program like this:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L . -l foobar -l barcat -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

Inspecting the dynamic section of `prog`:

```
$ readelf --dynamic prog

Dynamic section at offset 0x3ce8 contains 32 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfoobar.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libbarcat.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/imk/develop/so/scrap]
 ...[cut]...
```

we see that the dynamic linker has been told to load `libfoobar.so` first, before
`libbarcat.so` (and has been given a non-default library path, just so it can find those
non-installed libraries). We therefore predict that the dynamic linker will resolve
`bar` to the definition provided by `libfoobar.so`. And so it does:

```
$ ./prog
main calling foobar calling bar from foobar.cpp
```

Now let's just relink the program like this:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L . -l barcat -l foobar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

That has the effect of reversing the load order of `libfoobar.so` and `libbarcat.so`:

```
$ readelf --dynamic prog

Dynamic section at offset 0x3ce8 contains 32 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libbarcat.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfoobar.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/imk/develop/so/scrap]
 ...[cut]...
```

This will have the result:

```
$ ./prog
main calling foobar calling bar from barcat.cpp
```

that `libfoobar.so`'s references to `bar` are resolved to the definition provided by
`libbarcat.so`, notwithstanding that `libfoobar.so` provides its own different dynamically
visible definition. By default the dynamic linker binds a dynamically visible symbol to the
first definition it finds and does not look for another one. In that respect it is just like
the static linker.

It is possible, however, to relink `libfoobar.so` - recompilation not required - in such a way that its own
references to `bar` will be bound to its own definition come what may. From [`man ld`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> -Bsymbolic
>
> When creating a shared library, bind references to global symbols to the definition
> within the shared library, if any. Normally, it is possible for a program linked against
> a shared library to override the definition within the shared library. This option is
> only meaningful on ELF platforms which support shared libraries.

Accordingly we can relink `libfoobar.so` like:

```
$ g++ -shared -o libfoobar.so foobar.o -Wl,-Bsymbolic
```

After which:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L . -l barcat -l foobar -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
```

will yield:

```
$ ./prog
main calling foobar calling bar from foobar.cpp
```

nothwithstanding that `libbarcat.so` is loaded before `libfoobar.so`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup.  One of the reasons for the question was I guess more aimed at C++ ABI and CXX Versioning.  My understanding was that C++ versions symbols to enable backward compatibility in its runtime, and this seemed to be counter to that (a GCC 8.4 built lib fails *sometimes* when run on GCC 9+ systems).  However, based on this and prior analysis it seems this symbol is not versioned and thus can have this issue.

Second reason was for your explanation, which seems counter-intuitive since the symbol is present in the lib.  But I accept that I am wrong there.

Comment: I'll do some more experiments and try the -Bsymbolic flag to see if that has any adverse effects.  My concern there is if that flag forces this specific symbol to be used by a lib based on the GCC9 filesystem::path structure, and causing it to start crashing.