# Portable way to set file modification time in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a C++ application that needs to be portable between at least Ubuntu 15, FreeBSD 11, MacOS X and Windows 7 (compiled with GCC, clang and MSVC). All of these systems have a notion of a file with at least a modification date/time.

The question is: is there a way to set a *file modification time* using a single piece of C++ code that would work on all of these systems?

NB: By setting the file modification time I mean setting it to any specified value, *not* the current time (i.e. not the *touch* functionality).

Comment: I hate to say, but you can do it with boost.

Comment: In pure c++ it can't be done

Comment: Read the file and write it back.

Comment: You can use Boost.Filesystem, or simply `#ifdef _WIN32 ... #else ... #endif` because apart from Windows all those others support the POSIX APIs such as [`utimes()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimes.html). There's no difference between GNU/Linux, BSD and OS X in this respect, although GNU and newer FreeBSD might also support the higher-resolution `futimens` function.

Answer (score 7):

With [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), you can use this function to [get/set the time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#last_write_time):

```
void last_write_time(const path& p, const std::time_t new_time);
```

This is also available on some compilers as [experimental](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/last_write_time) feature on some compiles such as [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103209/experimental-filesystem-in-g) or [msvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx).  These use same API but different experimental namespace. So if you don't want to use boost, and as long as it's not yet integrated in the standard, you could make it portable with conditional compilation and using statement.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ Standard Library does not (yet) have any notion of file ([until filesystem will become part of the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs), which may happen with [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17)). At the moment, you need to rely on some cross-platform library such as [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) or [Qt](http://www.qt.io/).

Comment: No, filesystem will never become part of the STL. It is, however, due for inclusion in the Standard Library.