# macOS Clang C++17 filesystem header not found

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, c++17

I need to write a program using the (experimental) `C++17` filesystem library but `clang` on my **Mac (macOS 10.12.03)** doesn't seem to have the filesystem header included.

Since I'm required to use the `C++17`, I cannot use alternatives like the `Boost` library.

When I try to compile a sample program that just includes filesystem and `iostream` (and writes to `cout`)

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "test" << endl;
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
>clang test.cpp -std=c++1z

test.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

When I try the same using GCC 6.3 (installed via homebrew) I get:

```
>gcc-6 test.cpp  -std=c++17 
test.cpp:2:22: fatal error: filesystem: No such file or directory
 #include <filesystem>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

I also tried using experimental/filesystem instead which compiles using `gcc` but seems to try to compile for iOS leading to another error which seems to be related to `iostream`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccd5QiVt.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccd5QiVt.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The version of my clang is:

```
>clang --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I'm grateful for any helpful input since I couldn't find anything that solved my problem so far (although I might have been searching for the wrong terms).

If you need more information I'll gladly provide it but I hope to have included everything.

Comment: If the assignment has a requirement for this, perhaps the instructor should have told you how to actually achieve this (compiler and compiler flags)?

Comment: Well he only uses Linux so he didn't know how to do it on a mac...

Comment: @DeiDei Libc++ (Clang) will not ship `<filesystem>` in 4.0.

Comment: If you really have to do this with C++17 then either install a Linux VM on your Mac or see whether something like [homebrew](http://brew.sh) has C++17 + filesystem support yet.

Comment: For the gcc case [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30103992/1708801)

Comment: This question was asked *just* after the last changes were made for C++17, but it’s not the C++17 filesystem library if it’s experimental (or `std::experimental`).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Libc++, which is the C++ standard library on OS X, has not moved `<experimental/filesystem>` to `<filesystem>` yet because the specification is not stable.

Hopefully `<filesystem>` will be a part of the Clang 6.0 release. (We missed 5.0)

Comment: I see, thank you :)

But shouldn't it be able to include <experimental/filesystem>?

Comment: The rate at which Apple ships upstream libc++ changes is not up to me. Libc++ first shipped `<experimental/filesystem>` in 3.9 but Apple has yet to release it as a part of XCode. If you want to build your own version of libc++ from trunk it will have `<experimental/filesystem>`.

Comment: Including `<experimental/filesystem>` gets you the declarations, but to get the definitions you also have to link with `-lstdc++fs` (for libstdc++) or `I don't know` (for libc++). If someone knows, maybe they could update this answer?

Comment: Its a shame that filesystem is still not useable because Xcode is missing it and boost also misses some features from the specification (the charset u8string conversions for example). All we can do is wait for xcode 9.1 or later

Comment: Just installed Xcode 9.2 and still no `<experimental/filesystem>` :(

Answer (score 17):

Xcode 11 Beta now includes `<filesystem>`. Unlike the other answers indicating beta support in Xcode 10, Apple has mentioned this in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes?language=objc).

Also mentioned in the release notes, is this is only supported by iOS 13, macOS 10.15, watchOS 6, and tvOS 13. You will only be able to use `std::filesystem` for projects targeting these versions or later.

Comment: Is it possible <filesystem> being supported ONLY on the latest OS versions is related to Xcode 11 being in Beta?  That would seem unworkable if you intended to support MacOS 10.12 through 10.14.  Isn't there also Boost support built into earlier versions of MacOS?  Perhaps the thinking is that we call all just use Boost.Filesystem before 10.15?

Comment: @SMGreenfield my suspicion is that `libc++` on versions of macOS prior to 10.15 are lacking the filesystem implementation altogether. If you were to statically link `libc++` its _possible_ you could run your application on older systems (but there might be other issues with doing that depending on implementation). AFIK boost does not ship with macOS, but there is nothing stopping you from building/shipping with it.

Comment: I am on Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500) and there's no `filesystem`.

Comment: @I.Antonov I assure you it exists; I've been using it. Be sure to enable c++17 mode in your project. You may also need to change your SDK to one of the versions listed in my answer.

Comment: @BradAllred Hi, I went to Build Settings and then selected `C++17[-std=c++17]` from the `C++ Language Dialect` and still same.

Comment: @BradAllred if possible could you please check this thread and let me know where and what i'm doing wrong? I'd appreciate the help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943032/c-build-failed-on-x-code-osx-with-multiple-errors-file-io-is-unavailab?noredirect=1#comment104144855_58943032

Comment: @I.Antonov I also said you need to use one of the supported SDKs.

Answer (score 9):

In reply to Max Raskin: I've installed Xcode 10 Beta 4, from July 17, 2018, and this version does not have "#include <experimental/filesystem>" or "#include <filesystem>".

The [release notes](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_beta_4/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_10_beta_4.pdf) also do not mention libc++17 <filesystem>. The release notes *do* mention that the following are in Xcode 10: <any>, <optional>, and <variant>.

Example include file location:

`/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/experimental`

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

As mentioned in another answer `<filesystem>` is available in Xcode 11 Beta according to the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes):

> Clang now supports the C++17 `<filesystem>` library for iOS 13, macOS
>   10.15, watchOS 6, and tvOS 13. (50988273)

Here's hoping it's meant to stay this time!

**OLD ANSWER**

Just checked Xcode 10.2 Beta 4 and it has regular `<filesystem>`! For the curious, it's in `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/`.

**EDIT:**

Downloaded Xcode 10.2 (10E125) aaaaand ... `<filesystem>` is gone again. No mention whatsoever in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes). If you happen to have an Xcode version that contains `<filesystem>` lying around (like the Beta 4 I mentioned earlier) copying the file over seems to work okay:

```
$ sudo cp /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/filesystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/
```

Mind you, of course, every Xcode update will very likely break this workaround and make another copy necessary. Also, **there is probably a good reason why the beta implementation didn't make it into the release**. Proceed with caution...

Answer (score 3):

> Including  gets you the declarations, but to
>   get the definitions you also have to link with -lstdc++fs (for
>   libstdc++) or I don't know (for libc++). If someone knows, maybe they
>   could update this answer?

For libc++ you need to link with `-lc++experimental`

Answer (score 1):

I installed XCode 9.4 - no `<filesystem>`

But Homebrew came to the rescue with LLVM 6

```sh
brew update
brew install llvm
```

And with a change in `PATH`, I was away.

Comment: What was that change in `PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still interested, Xcode 10 Beta ships with libc++ that has experimental/filesystem

*UPDATE* one of Xcode 10 betas used to ship with it, perhaps by accident, Xcode 10.1 unfortunately, doesn't have it :(

Comment: just installed Beta 6 and no joy

Comment: 10.1 and still no action.

Comment: 10.2b3 has <filesystem>, but requires a library to be linked. I'm not sure it includes the required library.

Comment: @Max Raskin -- No love in 10.2.1 either?  I wonder if we might get a viable beta with std::filesystem by WWDC?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive directory walk using `ftw` in c, more details [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw).

On, `-std=c++17` for macOS version 10.xx, `filesystem` header is not available.

```
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

 
int list(const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type)
{
     if (type == FTW_NS)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     if (type == FTW_F)
     {
         printf("0%3o\t%s\n", status->st_mode&0777, name);
     }

     if (type == FTW_D && strcmp(".", name) != 0)
     {
         printf("0%3o\t%s/\n", status->st_mode&0777, name);
     }
     return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if(argc == 1)
     {
         ftw(".", list, 1);
     }
     else
     {
         ftw(argv[1], list, 1);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

output looks like following:

```
0755    ./Shivaji/
0644    ./Shivaji/20200516_204454.png
0644    ./Shivaji/20200527_160408.png
0644    ./Shivaji/20200527_160352.png
0644    ./Shivaji/20200520_174754.png
0644    ./Shivaji/20200520_180103.png
0755    ./Saif/
0644    ./Saif/Snapchat-1751229005.jpg
0644    ./Saif/Snapchat-1356123194.jpg
0644    ./Saif/Snapchat-613911286.jpg
0644    ./Saif/Snapchat-107742096.jpg
0755    ./Milind/
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1828.JPG
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1839.JPG
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1825.JPG
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1831.JPG
0644    ./Milind/IMG_1840.JPG
```